# Core Location in OS X 10.6 Snow Leopard

Tags: macos, core-location

Is there a way to utilize this?  10.6 uses it to determine the time zone; it can be disabled in Security.prefPane.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Core Location Framework Reference](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CoreLocation_Framework/index.html)